# Netty Proxy server

Tags: java, netty

I have the read the netty proxy server example. However I would like to know how to implement a client to talk to the proxy. The solution I am implementing is a server and it needs to connect to a socket server whenever a client connect to the server.So each client connected to the server will be able to send/receive data from another server.

I need help to inplement such architecture with netty because the server side is built on netty.

Answer (score 1):

It seems what you want to implement can be pretty much answered by the [Netty proxy example](http://static.netty.io/3.5/xref/org/jboss/netty/example/proxy/HexDumpProxyInboundHandler.html)

The code segment below shows how you can connect to the remote server once a new client channel is opened.

```
@Override
public void channelOpen(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ChannelStateEvent e)
        throws Exception {
    // Suspend incoming traffic until connected to the remote host.
    final Channel inboundChannel = e.getChannel();
    inboundChannel.setReadable(false);

    // Start the connection attempt.
    ClientBootstrap cb = new ClientBootstrap(cf);
    cb.getPipeline().addLast("handler", new OutboundHandler(e.getChannel()));
    ChannelFuture f = cb.connect(new InetSocketAddress(remoteHost, remotePort));

    outboundChannel = f.getChannel();
    f.addListener(new ChannelFutureListener() {
        public void operationComplete(ChannelFuture future) throws Exception {
            if (future.isSuccess()) {
                // Connection attempt succeeded:
                // Begin to accept incoming traffic.
                inboundChannel.setReadable(true);
            } else {
                // Close the connection if the connection attempt has failed.
                inboundChannel.close();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Once connected to the remote server, whatever the client sends (via inbound channel) is forwarded to the remote server (outbound channel).

I suggest you to follow and implement the proxy example if you haven't done it so already.